# How can I apply patches in the end?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a *.bbappend file with only `SRC_URI`'s. There are also patches, but they throw errors because it says that there is no file to patch. The file to patch is fetched in the base recipe.

How can I give the `SRC_URI`'s an order? I played around with both the layer priority and with the `append` suffixes, but the patch always fails due to missing files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The patches listed in `SRC_URI` are applied in the *same order* as they're listed in `SRC_URI`.

In other words, if you patches still fail to apply, you need to look into how they look like. You might have to play around with the parameter `striplevel` if you've created the patch in an unusual way. See [SRC_URI documentation](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SRC_URI) for more info on the parameter `striplevel` (and the other parameters).

Comment: You have brought me on the right path: With `bitbake -e recipe | grep ^SRC_URI` I noticed that I have overwritten the SRC_URIs from the actual recipe. Strange that it built anyway in some cases, probably due to step-by-step setup the former SRC_URIs has been built anyway and resided in the /tmp/work dir, while it has never been fetched directly again. That happened because I just had  `SRC_URI +=` in some cases where I thought the order would not care not being aware that I overwrote the former SRC_URIS